# Unir sentencia sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, .net

Tengo 4 checkboxs con que hacen referencia a unas columnas que tengo en una tabla de la base de datos, luego hay un boton que me permite ejecutar una sentencia y mostrarla en el datagridview.

Pongo un poco de la sentencia que utilizo

```
 If (un = "" And dos = "" And tres = "" And cuatro = "") Or (un <> "" And dos <> "" And tres <> "" And cuatro <> "") Then
                query = "select * from RT_Registros0 where TimeString >='" & fechaini & _
             "'and TimeString <='" & fechafin & "' order by TimeString desc"
            End If
 If un <> "" And dos = "" And tres = "" And cuatro = "" Then
                query = "select TimeString, " & Config.Variable1 & " from RT_Registros0 where TimeString >='" & fechaini & _
    "'and TimeString <='" & fechafin & "' order by TimeString desc"
            End If
```

un, dos, tres y cuatro son variables que estan vacias si no se ha seleccionado el checkbox y  las relleno con el nombre del checkbox seleccionado si esta seleccionado.
El problema viene cuando selecciono dos o mas checkbox, ya que yo estoy buscando si el campo esta vacio o no, y nunca se llega a dar.

Como puedo hacer para unir dos sentencias pero dentro de una misma tabla?creo que esto solucionaria mi error, aunque quiza no de la forma mas optima.

Comment: Voy a explicar algo mejor mi consulta:
Segun el checkbox seleccionado quiero hacer una consulta o otra.
Con los checkbox2 y 3 por ejemplo seleccionado la consulta seria:
select checkbox2, checkbox3 from tabla1

Comment: Con la explicación que das, dado que no se sabe a ciencia cierta lo que quieres, no se puede ver cuál es el problema o error en el código. Sugiero que [edit] la pregunta y seas más específico, o bien pongas directamente cuales son esos checkboxes y el efecto que quieres que cada uno tenga en la consulta que vas a lanzar en la base de datos.